# write all numbers in boldface

Tags: typography, bold, boldmath

I would like to write all numbers in boldface, is this possible?

For example, some command like \everymath{\displaystyle} = \everynumber{\textbf}

Thank you.

Here is a minimum MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}%{\article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
    
1, 2, 13, 19, -17 ->  \textbf{1, 2, 13, 19, -17}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want this in both math mode and text mode, and are you using pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

For number in math ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{boldoperators}     {OT1}{cmr} {bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}    {boldoperators}

\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathord}{boldoperators}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathord}{boldoperators}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathord}{boldoperators}{`2}
% etc ...

\showoutput

\begin{document}

$ 0 1 2 3 4 5 \mathbf{ABC} ABC\showlists$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For number in text it would be more complicated (aka next to impossible I would think unless you want to tinker with virtual fonts).